# navigator.getUserMedia is undefined on a php server that is not local, but locally it works perfectly

Tags: php, jquery, getusermedia, webcam-capture

I am making a platform that allows the capture and saving of a photo from the webcam, on localhost this works well, but when mounting it on a server that is not local, it does not work for me.

```
    function turnOnCamera(){
     canvas = document.getElementById("resultado");
     cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
     video = document.getElementById("camara");
    
    if(!navigator.getUserMedia){
         navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webKitGetUserMedia || navigator.                               moxGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;  
    }
    if(!window.ULR){
        window.ULR = window.webkitURL;
    }
    console.log(navigator.getUserMedia);
                     
    if(navigator.getUserMedia){                              
         navigator.getUserMedia({"video":true, "audio":false},
        
            function(stream){
                try{
                        localstream = stream;
                        video.srcObject = stream;
                        video.play();
                }catch(error){
                        video.srcObject = null;
                }
            },function(err){
                console.log("Error :" + err);
            });
    }else{
        console.log("Error :" + "No getUsermedia");
    }
}
```

Console response is undefined

Comment: Are you running this in a secure context? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Encryption_based_security

Comment: Maybe because the server is not with the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Yes, https seems to be necessary.